How to pass date via args in cronjob using amazon/aws-cli image
Trying to do something like this
containers:
        - name: aws-cli
          image: amazon/aws-cli
          env:
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: aws-creds
                  key: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: aws-creds
                  key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            - name: AWS_REGION
              value: {{ .Values.blobStore.config.s3.region }}
            - name: FROM
              value: $(date --date="-1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%d")
          args:
            - --no-progress
            - --delete
            - s3
            - sync
            - /data
            - "{{ .Values.backup.volumesDestPath }}/$(FROM)"

But what I get from $FROM is $(date --date="-1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%d") instead of actual date
